# How is this toilet flange attached?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I'm in the process of remodeling a bathroom and recently removed some dryrot plywood around the toilet.  I was originally expecting the toilet flange to be attached to the subfloor but it looks like it's somehow attached directly to the drain itself.

This looks eerily similar to the cast iron flange mentioned here: [How do I replace this cast iron toilet flange?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/20318/how-do-i-replace-this-cast-iron-toilet-flange)

Before I rent a pipe cutter and/or hire a plumber though, can I please get a second pair of eyes?  Is this indeed a permanently welded flange?  Or am I just missing something painfully obvious for how to remove it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you've got to cut it and should then use a Fernco coupling to plumb a modern PVC flange into the system.  In the past I've tried unscrewing cast iron but it always breaks, sometimes shattering past a convenient cut point!