# How Do I Connect PVC Pipe to a Toilet Waste Pipe?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, pipe

I'm renovating a bathroom. How do I connect a PVC pipe and toilet flange to the existing steel or cast iron waste pipe?

Should I use PVC/DWV foam core pipe?

(I think that the existing pipe is steel, but it might be cast iron.)

Pls see the lovely view of the existing toilet waste pipe below:

[image]

Is this the coupling I should use?

[image]

Comment: See [Tester101's link](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/20332/23295) for a, "4x3 rubber compression donut."

Comment: @Mazura Thank you for the comment. Is there a way to connect the original 4 in. pipe to 4 in. PVC, instead of reducing the size? Would having a wider pipe reduce the risk of clogs?

Comment: Sure, the one pictured is a 4x4". - Nothing you can get to flush down a toilet will clog a 3" pipe, but your codes may require 4". The trap in a toilet is ~2", so whatever IMO. 3" fittings are cheaper.

Comment: Make sure you use a heavy duty band, since this is in an inaccessible location. Also make sure it is specifically designed to use on cast iron on one side and ABS/PVC on the other. Check a good plumbing shop (as opposed to a "big-box").